# How to conditionally include a statement based on its type in a template?

Tags: c++, templates

If an argument of int* or int () function can be passed to a template, how to do something different depending on which one was passed to the template?

```
#include <type_traits>


template <typename GetterType>
class Getter
{public: 
    using isInvokable = std::is_invocable<GetterType>;


    using GotValueType = typename std::conditional_t<isInvokable::value,
                                    std::invoke_result<GetterType>,
                                    std::remove_pointer<GetterType>>::type;

    Getter(GetterType a) : getter(a) {}

    GetterType getter;

    GotValueType get() {
        if constexpr (isInvokable::value) return getter();
        else return *getter;
        // EVEN THOUGH INT* ISN'T CALLABLE IT'S STILL TRYING TO CALL GETTER
        }

    
};

int main() 
{
    int a = 0;
    Getter getter(&a);
    getter.get();
}
```

It won't compile because it's trying to call the template argument type even though what I pass to it isn't callable. And it tries to return an int* instead of an int.

Edit: Is there a way to conditionally compile one thing or another? I thought constexpr was used for this sort of thing in templates.

Edit2: This won't compile on Visual Studio 19 with ISO C++ 17 Standard (std:c++17):

```
'return': cannot convert from 'int' to 'int *'
```

Comment: For me anyting compiles fine: https://godbolt.org/z/PevK5s

Comment: Are you compiling C++17?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux On Visual Studio 19, 'return': cannot convert from 'int' to 'int *'

Comment: @Zebrafish What compilation flags are you passing to MSVC? `/std:c++latest`?

Comment: @AndyG Visual Studio 19 with ISO C++ 17 Standard (std:c++17)

Comment: @Zebrafish: I'm not sure what to tell you, it seems to [work fine](https://godbolt.org/z/6h3n9M) in 19.14 and up.

Comment: @AndyG So I have Visual Studio 19 Community Edition, but in the about details it says Version 16.4.5.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 which is version 16.X starts at MSVC++ 14.2 which is MSVC executable version 19.20. Version 16.4 (what you have) uses MSVC++ 12.24 which is MSVC executable version 19.24. They both seem to compile this code just fine. Make sure there isn't something wrong with your source file like a non-printable character somewhere.

Comment: @rustyx Thank you,yes, that makes it work. How recent a feature is this? I know constexpr is really old, but it's interesting it doesn't do what I expected without that flag

Comment: @Zebrafish `if constexpr` is from C++17, the newest official version of the language (but C++20 should be out soon). It is not an old feature.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux OK it's resolved with the /std:c++latest flag. Do I delete this question now?

Comment: @Zebrafish No. There was an actual a problem and you found a practical solution. Unless someone else posts an answer in the next few minutes, you should post the answer yourself. That way this question can be useful to future readers who may have the same problem as you.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I really doubt it, the title and body is highly specific.

Comment: @PasserBy Still, it can be linked as a duplicate by someone who knows about it. And the title can be improved.

Answer (score 3):

`is_invocable` and `if constexpr` are C++17 features. MSVC 2019 by default compiles in C++14 mode.

To enable C++17, configure the project to compile with `/std:c++17` or `/std:c++latest`

[image: msvc c++latest]

The [`/std`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=vs-2019) flag is supported since VS 2017.

Comment: Thank you, /std:c++17 doesn't work but /std:c++latest does

Comment: Strange, /std:c++17 [works](https://godbolt.org/z/xrEMYv) for me.